# Azure Active Directory Groups/Roles

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to figure out how to create a windows azure active directory group and/or role from the web portal. Am I missing something obvious here or? I can create users, and assign them to the 2 built in roles, but how do I create a new role? or group?

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I haven't tried this yet, but the PowerShell extensions should be able to do this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx

Look under "Manage group and role membership" for details on the relevant commands.

I would also assume that the Graph API could handle it.  I too was hoping that the Azure Management Portal would let us do it in their GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the way to add groups, etc is via the graph api or as suggested above by PS scripts. The graph api is amazingly powerful, albeit not as convenient as if this funcitonality lived within the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. create app roles and assign security groups to them (AAD Premium is
   required)
2. enable security groups as claims (AAD Free is enough)

Follow this official manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps